# How to convert values in a field to different fields in Google Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two distinct values in a field and some aggregates based on that, how would I convert these values into two different fields and then have the aggregates accordingly.

What I have:

```
user_id       status              amount
101           deposit             100
101           credit              300
101           deposit             700
102           deposit             1000
102           credit              200
102           credit              500
```

What I want:

```
user_id      credit     deposit 
101          300        800
102          700        1000
```

Could anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT user_id,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='credit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) credit,
       SUM(CASE WHEN status='deposit' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) deposit 
FROM src_table
GROUP BY user_id
```